# Return Top 1 from any SQL query/view/CTE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to return only ONE record so that I can get all the column calls via the code below?

```
using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
    dtResults.Load(reader);

    return dtResults;
}
```

So right now this will return ALL X records from the query and I only need to return 1 record so I can plug the columns data types etc. into my Grid control.

We can't just add `SELECT Top 1` because some of the queries start with a CTE etc.

We can't wrap it around another query because sometimes the query have `Order By`s

We can't force the users to add a separate query that will mimic what we want to do.

Here is the error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    (SELECT O.Department, O.ID
     FROM dbo.table1 e
     LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 O ON e.Department = O.Department
     ORDER BY ID) x
```

Comment: Just run `reader.Read` once and don't load it to a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need metadata only, use `.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)`

If you want to read one row, use SQL's OFFSET/FETCH clause. They are appended at the end of the statement, so might work for your case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Note that you must provide some ordering clause.

```
SELECT 
    O.Department
    ,O.ID
FROM dbo.table1 e
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 O
ON e.Department = O.Department
order by O.ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you cannot use `Order by` with sub-query in SQL server.

```
select top 1 * 
from 
(
    SELECT 
        O.Department
        ,O.ID
    FROM dbo.table1 e
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 O
    ON e.Department = O.Department
) 
Order by  
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

[sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should do what you want. It'll return metadata for the command in question.

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'SELECT O.Department, O.ID
 FROM dbo.table1 e
 LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 O ON e.Department = O.Department
 ORDER BY ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is just unecessary. You can use `top (1)` and `order by` directly in the outer query:

```
select top(1) o.department, o.id
from dbo.table1 e
left join dbo.table2 o on e.department = o.department
order by id
```